# How to make appium session remotely with a device which is on another machine

Tags: android, adb, appium, appium-android

**Use Case**

I have one mobile device connected on a laptop whose IP is `10.132.222.23`. Now I want to make appium session with the device from another laptop.

This is possible when we do it from Appium Desktop, but I want to explore a command line option to do the same.

**What I did**

from my laptop, I tried to run the command

```
appium -a 10.132.222.23 -p 4734
```

However, this fails.
I believe that I am missing some essentials parameter to make the session.

Comment: machine where appium server is running and machine where device is connected are on same network ?

Comment: Yes!!all the relevant devices are on same network!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your remote laptop(one that is connected with mobile device) start the appium server:

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --session-override
```

> Find the ip address of remote laptop.

In your other laptop, initialize **AppiumDriver** and **DesiredCapabilities**

```
AppiumDriver driver;
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
//add your capabilities

driver= new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

> where xxx.xxx.xx.xx is the ip address of remote laptop.